# Huggingface transformers: cannot import BitsAndBytesConfig from transformers

Tags: huggingface-transformers

Following through the [Huggingface quantization guide](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/main_classes/quantization), I installed the following:

```bash
pip install transformers accelerate bitsandbytes
```

(It yielded transformers 4.26.0, accelerate 0.16.0, bitsandbytes 0.37.0, which seems to match the guide’s requirements.)

Then ran the first line of the offload code in Python:

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig
```

It however resulted in the following error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'BitsAndBytesConfig' from 'transformers' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/__init__.py)`.

Doing `grep BitsAndBytesConfig -r /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages` yields nothing.

Is there a step I might have skipped, or a version inconsistency I could work around?

Answer (score 7):

BitsAndBytesConfig was [added only recently](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/commit/3668ec17165dbb7823f3bc7e190e1733040c3af8), and the latest release dates back to earlier.

The online documentation is generated from the source’s mdx, so it sometimes references things that are not yet released. However, it can be tried by [installing from source](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#install-from-source):

```bash
pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
```

Answer (score 0):

Install from the original github repository

```
pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers
from transformers import BitsAndBytesConfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Change collab environment to GPU necessary
and run this :

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/accelerate.git
!pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git
!pip install bitsandbytes
```